# Java remove unwanted spaces in a text file and replace with character

Tags: java, regex, writer, reader

I have the following text file. I want to remove the lines and spaces so that the text file has a clear delimter to process. I cannot think of any way to remove the gaps between lines, is there a way?

```
Student+James Smith+Status: Current Student+Student+James Fits+Status: Not a current Student
```

Textfile

```
Student
     James Smith

Status: Current Student

Student
     James Fits

Status: Not a current Student
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this

```
a.replaceAll("\\s+","");
```

removes whitespaces. 
You could remove end of line characters in a similar fashion

```
a.replaceAll("\n","");
```

Where 'a' is a String.

Comment: `\s` contains `\n\s\r\f `

Comment: ah, good to know. Been long since I had to use it. Thanks for the helpful insight, friend.

Answer (score 0):

use a `regex` take the whole text in to a string and

```
string txt = "whole String";
String formatted = txt.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "-");
```

this will result in changing `+` sign and `" "` to replace with `"-"` sign. so now you have a specific deleimeter.

Answer (score 0):

Something like *find* `\s*\r?\n\s*` *replace* `+`

Trims whitespace and adds delimiter '+'
Result:

```
Student+James Smith+Status: Current Student+Student+James Fits+Status: Not a current Student
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this one.

```
\n+\s*
```

just use it like this :

```
yourStrVar.replaceAll("\n+ *", "+")
```